# Clean jenkins queue of jobs when jobs of the same branch are pending

Tags: jenkins

Our team is using merge requests to ensure code reviews.
We use jenkins as our CI server.

Some times while reviewing a given branch we push a lot of commits to a given branch. And in jenkins we trigger a build for each commit.

Is there a way to clear the jenkins job queue automatically if it detects multiple jobs for the same branch? Just keeping the most recent job? to ensure the latest commit is built.

Comment: Are you using [tag:jenkins-pipeline]? This has the `milestone` step.

Comment: I am not using that plugin. How does the milestone step help in this case?

Comment: It clears all previous builds that reached the milestone. See [docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Milestone+Step+Plugin).

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. Here you assume that there are two builds running at the same time. My server can only process one job at a time. And the newer builds stay in the queue in the state "pending". But I only want the most recent build to run. The builds between the running build and the latest can be aborted.

Comment: I see, think you're right. But adding more slaves to build jobs is generally a good move anyways ;-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use some groovy code to check if there is another job in the queue , and if so clean the queue or abort your current build.

here is an example to clean the queue

```
def branchName = build.environment.get("GIT_BRANCH_NAME")

def buildNo = build.environment.get("BUILD_NUMBER")

println "checking if need to clean the queue for" + branchName + "  build      number : " + buildNo

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.each { 
    println("${it.task.name}:")
}

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith(branchName) }.each {
  q.cancel(it.task) 
}
```

Comment: btw, won't this script cancel the current job?

Comment: the current job will continue to run , it will clean only the queue. If you want to abort the current job you need to modify the script.

you need to add a build step : *Execute system Groovy script* , make sure you install this one - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

Comment: I don't want the current job to abort, but from your snippet the second loop should contain the job that executes this script

Comment: The first loop print the queue , the second cancel specific branch that wait in the queue.